# Wordpress orderby in query rendering same posts

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, sql-order-by

I'm trying to loop through posts and generate a few different posts each time the page is hit.  I've used this exact same process before and it's always worked fine, but for some reason on this site it's behaving differently. It will load random posts, but only the first time.  In other words, it's loading them in a scattered order, but it loads the same posts in the same order every time.  Instead, I want it loading completely different posts every the page is hit. I have no idea what's going on with it! I've tested plugins and themes already, no luck.  Any ideas?

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 5
    );

$wp_query = new WP_query($args);
while(have_posts() ) : the_post();

?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php 
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Comment: update: I pulled the same code bit off the wordpress install and ran it on a local install and it worked properly - so any ideas outside of plugins and themes that could be interfering with the orderby function?

Comment: try to disable plugin,and chenge wordpress difficult theme and check.

Answer (score 0):

Any installed theme or plugin may have used orderby, so try to remove it first when you're using for your own query.

```
<?php
    remove_all_filters('posts_orderby'); //Reset orderby filters
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page' => 5
        );

    $wp_query = new WP_query($args);
    while(have_posts() ) : the_post();

    ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php 
        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_query(); 
    ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the recommendation - I had tried this before and double checked it this morning, no luck. Still having the same issue even after resetting the filter.  It's so odd to me that it DOES get posts randomly, but that it doesn't change what posts it gets when reloaded.